# glibc posix_memalign allocation overhead

Tags: glibc

I was trying to understand the memory overhead associated with `posix_memalign` - in other words, if `posix_memalign` relies on boundary tagging and how big such tagging is.

So I wrote the following (very simple) program (linux x86_64 platform, "gcc -m64"):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int   i;
    void* prev;
    void* memp;

    int align = atoi(argv[1]);
    int alloc = atoi(argv[2]);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        if (posix_memalign(&memp, align, alloc))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "allocation failed\n");
            return 1;
        }

        if (i == 0)
            printf("allocated %d bytes at 0x%08x\n", alloc, memp);
        else
            printf("allocated %d bytes at 0x%08x (offset: %d)\n",
                   alloc, memp, (int)(memp-prev));

        prev = memp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, the result baffle me...

```
$ /tmp/test 8 1
allocated 1 bytes at 0x0133a010
allocated 1 bytes at 0x0133a030 (offset: 32)
allocated 1 bytes at 0x0133a050 (offset: 32)
allocated 1 bytes at 0x0133a070 (offset: 32)
allocated 1 bytes at 0x0133a090 (offset: 32)

same for allocations of 2 to 24 bytes, until:

$ /tmp/test 8 25
allocated 25 bytes at 0x0198c010
allocated 25 bytes at 0x0198c040 (offset: 48)
allocated 25 bytes at 0x0198c070 (offset: 48)
allocated 25 bytes at 0x0198c0a0 (offset: 48)
allocated 25 bytes at 0x0198c0d0 (offset: 48)

same for allocations of 26 to 40 bytes, until:

$ /tmp/test 8 41
allocated 41 bytes at 0x0130c010
allocated 41 bytes at 0x0130c050 (offset: 64)
allocated 41 bytes at 0x0130c090 (offset: 64)
allocated 41 bytes at 0x0130c0d0 (offset: 64)
allocated 41 bytes at 0x0130c110 (offset: 64)
```

So I initially concluded the minimum allocation was 32 bytes and that `posix_memalign` used an 8 byte boundary tag.

The same results were obtained with a 16 byte alignment. But things got weird with a 32 byte alignment:

```
$ /tmp/test 32 1
allocated 1 bytes at 0x0064c040
allocated 1 bytes at 0x0064c080 (offset: 64)
allocated 1 bytes at 0x0064c120 (offset: 160)
allocated 1 bytes at 0x0064c160 (offset: 64)
allocated 1 bytes at 0x0064c200 (offset: 160)

same for allocations of 2 to 24 bytes, until:

$ /tmp/test 32 25
allocated 25 bytes at 0x01e0c040
allocated 25 bytes at 0x01e0c0c0 (offset: 128)
allocated 25 bytes at 0x01e0c140 (offset: 128)
allocated 25 bytes at 0x01e0c1c0 (offset: 128)
allocated 25 bytes at 0x01e0c240 (offset: 128)

same for allocations of 26 to 40 bytes, until:

$ /tmp/test 32 41
allocated 41 bytes at 0x00a72040
allocated 41 bytes at 0x00a720a0 (offset: 96)
allocated 41 bytes at 0x00a72160 (offset: 192)
allocated 41 bytes at 0x00a721c0 (offset: 96)
allocated 41 bytes at 0x00a72280 (offset: 192)
```

Can anybody explain such behaviour? I am at a total loss...

Answer (score 0):

posix_memalign only guarantees a min alignment.  so if you just coincidentally get something like `0x00a72000`, that might be aligned to `0x1000` bytes, but that doesn't mean a lot of memory was wasted to pad it that way.  even your first example *almost* showed this -- it started at `0x0198c010` and incremented by `0x30` after each one.  eventually that'll hit an address with many low bits cleared.

keep in mind that the malloc in glibc is not a "stupid" one that just hands out pages/chunks linearly.  if you want to learn more about its internal behavior, you should read about the allocators that it's based on.  glibc uses [ptmalloc](http://www.malloc.de/en/) which is based on [dlmalloc](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html).  i don't think the [glibc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/) itself goes into depth about its internal design decisions.

Comment: But how does one explain the fact that the offset between subsequent allocations varies (i.e. the results of the second example)?

Comment: i see nothing bad or unusual there.  the ptmalloc has multiple arenas that it gives out memory from.